# How can I keep different values on ArrayList using recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I'm doing a permutation using a recursive method, and I want to keep the permutations in the ArrayList. I'm doing this bc I want to delete if a permutation is equal to another - like 123 is equal to 132, 124 is equal to 142. I want to avoid repetition.

The permutations are like this:

```
(1) : 1 2 3 
(2) : 1 2 4 
(3) : 1 3 2 
(4) : 1 3 4
(5) : 1 4 2 
(6) : 1 4 3 
(7) : 2 1 3 
(8) : 2 1 4 
(9) : 2 3 1 
(10) : 2 3 4 
(11) : 2 4 1 
(12) : 2 4 3 
(13) : 3 1 2 
(14) : 3 1 4
(15) : 3 2 1
(16) : 3 2 4
(17) : 3 4 1 
(18) : 3 4 2
(19) : 4 1 2
(20) : 4 1 3 
(21) : 4 2 1
(22) : 4 2 3 
(23) : 4 3 1 
(24) : 4 3 2
```

But when I ask to print the ArrayList, the list is like this:

```
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
432
```

Here's the code: (The method 'getCyclesThroughPermutation' is called inside main)

```
private static int cont = 0;
private static int[] permutation;

public static void getCyclesThroughPermutation(byte[][] matrix, int vertices){
    
    allPermutations = new ArrayList<>();
    
    /* This will represent all the vertices. */
    int allVertices[] = new int[vertices];

    /* Assigning values for the vertices array.*/
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++){
        value++;
        allVertices[i] = value;
    } 

    /* Calls the permute method. */
    App.permute(allVertices);
}

public static ArrayList<int[]> allPermutations = new ArrayList<>();


/**
 * Main method: receives the array whose elements will be permutated.
 * @param vertices
*/
public static void permute(int[] vertices) {

    //i < vertices.length
    for (int i = 3; i < 4; i++){
        permutation = new int[i];
        permute(vertices, 0, allPermutations);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < allPermutations.size(); i++){
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < allPermutations.get(i).length; j++){
            System.out.print(allPermutations.get(i)[j]);
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Recursive method that implements the permutations.
 * @param vertices
 * @param n
*/
private static void permute(int[] vertices, int n, ArrayList<int[]> allPermutations) {



    /* If the given number is equal to the permutation array length: */
    if (n == permutation.length) {
        /* Count plus 1 (permutation accomplished). */
        cont++;

        // for (int i=0; i < permutation.length; i++) System.out.print(permutation[i] + " ");
        
        int[] clone = permutation.clone();
        Arrays.sort(clone);

        if(!allPermutations.contains(clone)){
            //System.out.println("Não sou um clone.");
            allPermutations.add(permutation);
            printPermutation();
        }
        else {
            //System.out.println("Sou um clone.");
        }

    } else {
        /* For each vertice of the vertices array: */
        for (int i=0; i < vertices.length; i++) {

            /* Boolean that keeps track if will be repetitions. */
            boolean found = false;

            /* For each index of the permutation array: */
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                /* If the values are equal, the found variable will be true. */
                if (permutation[j]==vertices[i]) found = true;
            }

            /* If there's no equal values: */
            if (!found) {
                /* The permutation array in the n index will be equal to the vertice. */
                permutation[n] = vertices[i];
                /* And now, we permute again, but the next index will change. */
                permute(vertices, n+1, allPermutations);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void printPermutation() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("(" + cont + ") : ");
    for (int i=0; i < permutation.length; i++) System.out.print(permutation[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: Seems like a use-case for a Set, rather than a list, no?

Comment: So your expected output for input `[1, 2, 3, 4]` should be `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]`?

Comment: yeah, the input is a adjacency matrix, but the numbers are 1, 2, 3 and 4, and the out put should be the first list that i showed